# Row separator in floated list

Tags: css, list, css-float, separator

This is what I want to achieve.

```
[Item 0]   [Item 1]   [Item 2]   [Item 3]
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[Item 4]   [Item 5]   [Item 6]   [Item 7]
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[Item 8]   [Item 9]   [Item10]   [Item11]
```

Current code:

```
<ul><li>[Item 0]</li>...</ul>
li { float: left; }
```

Yes, rocket science. It's a floated list with row separators. If the separator was a solid line, it could be achieved with border/background. But it's a custom dashed line, so a background wouldn't flow continuously between the items.

Is there some cool CSS wizardry to do this that I'm not aware of, or do I have to use separate `<ul>` for each row?

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ZvcZL/

Comment: @thirtydot <del>Would that work with a custom dashed line (image)?</del> I guess it would. Add as answer and I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the `:before` selector.

```
ul li:nth-child(4n+5):before {
    display: block;
    background: url(separator.png) repeat-x;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I may have totally misunderstood, but would this not work?

http://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/85UZz/3/

**EDIT:** Here's the image masked out on the last row http://jsfiddle.net/csswizardry/85UZz/4/

Answer (score 1):

you could add a span after the 4th li on each row then style that the way you want it, but make sure to set `display: inline-block;`

Comment: Hm. Would it be possible to do this with pure CSS instead? Like `li:nth-child(4n):after { width: 100%; background: url(bg.png) repeat-x; }`

Answer (score 1):

Only wizardry I can think of would be [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/VgbvW/). Basically using `nth-child(n)` to achieve the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

here is a super basic version of what your asking...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>untitled</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <style>
        ul {
            width: 300px;
        }

        ul > li {
            float: left;
            margin-left: 15px;
            list-style: none; 
        }

        span {
            width: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
            border-bottom: 1px dashed #000;
            height: 3px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <span></span>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <span></span>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>12</li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

using some JS could work as well, iterate something to say every # of li's put in a span that has a specific style.

hope this helps and clarifies.

Comment: Please stop deleting your answer. You can't put an `<span>` directly inside an `<ul>`.